# Why ajax calls in Chrome Browser (in mobile and tablet versions) are failing?

Tags: php, ajax, google-chrome, browser, laravel-5.4

I am developing a web application for a project and facility management.
based on Laravel 5.4, MySql as the backend db.

In this aplication, I have a javascript to fetch info inside a room when
I click on the thumbnail image of the room.

the js looks like like

```js
$(".thumbnail").click(function() {
    functionname = 'fetchAllRacksInARoom';
    fulladdress = host5+functionname;
    //alert(fulladdress); //just to check everything as expected
    var image_id = $(this).attr("id");

    $("#left_top").load( fulladdress, {
                     image_id: image_id },
       function(responseText, textStatus, xhr){
          //alert('response text =  ' + responseText);
       }
    );

    //alert ('Image_id clicked =' + image_id);
});
```

The host is defined in the beginning.

It works flawlessly on desktop versions of Chrome, Edge41(Win10) works, Edge40(Win10) does not work, IE11, Opera etc., on a live server i.e. production environment.  In development environment, all browsers work absolutely normal.

When I use chrome browser in a tablet, the ajax calls are failing.
The textStatus, I see "error", obviously, no responseText. The
alerts show the correct address and image id that is touched.

In my mobile Mi browser, it works normal. Opera browser in a tablet works but it messes the css.

My own touchscreen laptop works immaterial of touch or click events. I guess it has to do something with touch or click.

Why the chrome browser in a mobile or tablet, I do not get any response?

Thank you all in advance for taking time to help me.

Comment: can you provide a context for this script? html elements, expected content for this url, etc...?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The context is to obtain how many racks inside the room image clicked. The data to be retrieved is the rack id numbers. These numbers when I click further, I will get the content Id numbers kept in each of the racks.

Comment: if the `textStatus` is error, it is a server error. If you `alert(xhr.statusText);` in the complete-function, you will get more info. Also, check your Laravel error log for failed requests to whatever the value of `fulladdress` is.

Comment: I see "error" no other information. Again desktop versions of Chrome, Edge41 work normal. It is the tablet and mobile versions of Chrome do not work. The Laravel log file (inside the storage) did not record anything.

Comment: I do not whether I am able to solve completely but I seem to have found the solution. The problem (might be), multiple browsers and sessions logged in Laravel and the sessions clash might have led to the issue (same user having multiple active sessions across browsers and devices) but this particular point still needs to be examined. The final solution seems to be simple. I have removed the host in the above script and supplied only the controller and function, I got success in mobile chrome browser. I have deleted the entire sessions data and cache before doing this. It worked.